# What are a few time-consuming operations in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, cpu, benchmarking

I'm looking to write a quick benchmark program that can be compiled and run on various machines. Rather than using commercially/open-sourceally available options, I'd rather have my own to play around with threading and algorithm optimization techniques.

I have a couple that I use already, which include recursively calculating the nth number of the Fibonacci sequence, and of seeding/rand()ing a few thousand times.

Are there any other algorithms that are relatively simple, but at the same time computationally-intensive (and possibly math-related)?

**(Note that these operations will be implemented in the C language.)**

Comment: So what do you want to benchmark? Integer performance? Floating point? RAM access speed? The size and speed of the various cache levels? The only thing that I can see is that you aren't interested in I/O (which probably dominates for the tasks most people do).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) is usually a fun one, but don't give it very large inputs if you want it to finish in your lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

**Fractals**

(at various resolutions) [Some fractal source in C (without opengl)](http://www.ciram.unibo.it/~strumia/Fractals/FractalGallery2/FractalGallery2.html)

Comment: +1: I like this one because you get to enjoy the results. Or if you use an algorithm that improves itself iteratively you can watch it working, which is ever more fun!

Comment: Yep, just don't use a GPU through OpenGL obviously this will defeat the benchmarking purpose. You can also have fun with lots of complex math that together abuse the math API for benchmarking and make a pretty fractal

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you wanted to make your own, but perhaps you could draw upon existing benchmarks for inspiration. [The Computer language benchmark game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/) has run many programming languages through a a set of benchmarks. Perhaps you can get some ideas looking at their benchmarks.

Some quick ideas of the top of my head:

- Matrix multiplication: mulitplying 2
  large matrices is relatively
  computationally intensive, though you
  will have to take caching into account
- Generating prime numbers
- Integer factorization
- Numerical methods for solving ODEs -
  [Runge-kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) for example

Answer (score 2):

Inverting big matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You could calc big primes or factorizing integers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [NAS Parallel Benchmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAS_Parallel_Benchmarks).  These were originally written by [NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/) in Fortran for supercomputers using MPI (and are still available that way), but there are also C, Java, and OpenMP implementations available now.

Most of these are **very** computationally intensive, as they're intended to be representative of numerical algorithms used in scientific computing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to calculate thousands or millions [pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) digits. There are quite a few [formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) for that task.

Comment: Fabrice Bellard of QEmu fame is the discoverer of the most efficient Pi calculation formula ... bellard.org/pi multi-talented! ... and he won a source obfuscation contest with the implementation!

Comment: I have read an article about Fabrice Bellard in a Linux magazine. Smart guy!

Answer (score 1):

You have some really nice ones in [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/), those are all math related and can be time consuming as you want using higher values.

Comment: not really, with the apropriate algorithms (which is what the puzzles try to motivate) most problems scale reasonably well.  unfortunately, for many of those problems common hardware is fast enough that brute-force is fast enough, sometimes by a huge margin.

Comment: i know but if he uses some of the harder problems (and those that incresing the values makes them much more time consuming) he will get algorithms worth using in a benchmark app

Answer (score 0):

Finding prime numbers is considered quite time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

This does a lot of addition:

```
int c = 0; 
for (int n = 0; n < INT_MAX; n++)
    for (int m = 0; m < INT_MAX; m++)
        c++;

std::cout << c;
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. Any decentcompiler will see that you did absolutely nothing with n or m, and will therefore optimize it all away.

Comment: And adding numbers is one of the things computers do best. Arbitrary width float multiplication would be more intensive!

Comment: @Ken White - have made adjustments.

Comment: @Aiden Bell - what if you did *even more* addition?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the benchmarks from the language shootout: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/

However: benchmarks are only benchmarks and don't necessarily tell you a lot about the real world and can, on the contrary, be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try parallelism, do lots of matrix math. The size of your matrix you can use will be limited by memory, but you can do as many iterations as you want.

This will stress the SIMD instructions that modern CPUs come with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a tsort (Turbo Sort) with a very large input set.  I understand this to be a common operation.

Answer (score 0):

Heuristics for [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problems are a fun way to get some CPU intensive code. You could code a "solution" :) for one of [Karps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems) NP-Complete problems.